# t-sql represent a repeating decimal value as a percentage

Tags: t-sql

So I have two columns TotalBoxes, and BoxesTicked, my total is 33, and the number of boxes ticked is 2.

So 2/33 gives me .06 (repeating)

T-sql returns 0. How do I write the T-SQL to return .06 only.

```
DECLARE @TotalBoxes int
DECLARE @TotalTicked int

SET @TotalBoxes = 33
SET @TotalTicked = 2

PRINT @TotalTicked/@TotalBoxes
PRINT ROUND(@TotalTicked/@TotalBoxes, 4,2)
PRINT CAST(@TotalTicked/@TotalBoxes as DECIMAL(4,2))
```

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your variables are `INT` and their division is shown as an `INT` by SQL Server. If you could cast either of them to a data type with decimals (like `DECIMAL` or `NUMERIC`), then the division would have decimal numbers.

A caveat to cast an integer to a decimal is multiplying by one like `1.0` which is a decimal (note the decimal point).

```
DECLARE @TotalBoxes int
DECLARE @TotalTicked int

SET @TotalBoxes = 33
SET @TotalTicked = 2

PRINT @TotalTicked * 1.0 /@TotalBoxes
PRINT ROUND(@TotalTicked * 1.0/@TotalBoxes, 4,2)
PRINT CAST(@TotalTicked * 1.0/@TotalBoxes as DECIMAL(4,2))
```

Result:

```
0.060606060606
0.060600000000
0.06
```